# real time chat app with django workds with channels but not after using redis and deploy to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, redis, chat, real-time

hello I am working on chatting app with django channels works perfectly in localhost but once I used redis and deployed to heroku I can't send anymessage the websocket always close,
my **settings.py**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}
```

I am using **redis and postgresql addons**,
and my **Procfile** is like this

```
web: daphne myproject.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker --settings=myproject.settings -v2
```

the error from heroku logs --tail

```
2022-01-07T23:33:49.877754+00:00 app[web.1]: raise InvalidChannelLayerError(
2022-01-07T23:33:49.877754+00:00 app[web.1]: channels.exceptions.InvalidChannelLayerError: ROUT
ING key found for default - this is no longer needed in Channels 2.
2022-01-07T23:33:49.877914+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-07 23:33:49,877 INFO     failing WebSocket
 opening handshake ('Internal server error')
2022-01-07T23:33:49.878083+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-07 23:33:49,878 WARNING  dropping connecti
on to peer tcp4:10.1.83.62:25575 with abort=False: Internal server error
2022-01-07T23:33:49.878720+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-07 23:33:49,878 DEBUG    WebSocket closed
for ['10.1.83.62', 25575]
```

why it works perfectly in my localhost because I am using only this

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, did you find a solution to your problem? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's disabled on Heroku.

As it's [mentioned in docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#in-memory-channel-layer), you shouldn't use it in production:

> In-memory channel layers operate with each process as a separate layer. This means that no cross-process messaging is possible. As the core value of channel layers is to provide distributed messaging, in-memory usage will result in sub-optimal performance, and ultimately data-loss in a multi-instance environment.

So you have to come up with a Redis solution.

Comment: yes and that's why I am using channels_redis as it is mentionned in docs 'channels_redis is the only official Django-maintained channel layer supported for production use.'

Comment: I said in localhost I am using In-memory but if u see as I mentioned before my settings.py configuration I use redis .....and I don't know why my websocket close when I want to send a message ....